# swift iOS filter on array containing uitableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func convertPointToIndexPath(_ point: CGPoint) -> (UITableView, IndexPath)? {
        if let tableView = [tableView1, tableView2, tableView3].filter({ $0.frame.contains(point) }).first {
            let localPoint = scrollView.convert(point, to: tableView)
            let lastRowIndex = focus?.0 === tableView ? tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1 : tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: localPoint) ?? IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: 0)
            return (tableView, indexPath)
        }

        return nil
    }
```

So i got this method, which converts a CGPoint into the indexPath of the given uitableView. I struggle with the filter-Method on the array which contains uitableViews.

I got an array outside of this method which contains any number of uitableViews. For example:

```
 public var littleKanbanColumnsAsTableViews: [UITableView] = []
```

So i got to make a change inside of the method. Like this:

```
if let tableView = littleKanbanColumnsAsTableViews.filter({ $0.frame.contains(point)}).first { ... }
```

Now when i click on any tableView on the gui, i track the coordinates of the point and transform it on the belonging tableview with the frame.contains(point) method.

My problem is that the filter is not working, it always gives me the first tableView back, no matter which tableview is clicked. Why it doesn't work with my littleKanbanColumnsAsTableViews-Array?

One hint:

```
 let tableView = littleKanbanView.littleKanbanColumnsAsTableViews[3]
```

When i indexing its direct then it works. But i want it depending on which tableView is containing the clicked point.

Here is my array with the tableViews, in this case the array contains 5 tableviews.

[array containing tableviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdq8W.png)

Now i want to filter the tableView out of them, which includes the point from tapping on this tableView. How can i achieve this?

For more understanding, i add the ui, here is it:

[UI of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddCss.png)

When i click on this tableView it works, because it is the first element in my array of tableViews. So for this case the convertPointToIndexPath-Method is working.

But when i scroll horizontally to the second tableView for example and click on that, it doesn't work. Because I think the method gives me always the first element back, but i thought it filters it with the given condition.

What is the problem, why doesn't work the condition`{ $0.frame.contains(point)}`? It have to localize the tableView when the coordinates of the point are tracked.

Comment: Are you displaying all 3 table views in one screen ? If so it could be better to use sections in table view.

Comment: No, i have something like trello. I enabled paging for the scrollview, my tableviews are on this scrollview. Per page i display only one tableview.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is better suited for it. Refer https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview

Comment: But i have built my project on tableViews now.

Answer (score 0):

## Preferred Solution:

In this case the moment the first satisfying condition is met, the rest of the elements are not traversed.

```
if let tableView = littleKanbanColumnsAsTableViews.first(where: { $0.frame.contains(point) }) {

}
```

## Not so efficient solution:

In this case all the elements in the array are traversed to build an array of table views that satisfy the condition. Then the first element of that filtered array is chosen.

```
if let tableView = (littleKanbanColumnsAsTableViews.filter{ $0.frame.contains(point)}).first {

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the problem is still remaining. Maybe the problem is another.